# Margin from one element obscuring hover state of another

Tags: html, css, margin, flexbox

I have a Flexbox based nav menu with a logo aligned in the horizontal center of inline links. Every pen or fiddle I tried making of this doesn't replicate what I'm getting for some reason, but you can go [to this Flexbox test here](http://www.smoresday.us/) which is almost exactly what I'm working from and if you go into an inspector and add an anchor to the main logo image you'll see what I mean.

The way this is set up is the third link has a left margin of auto applied to fill in the extra gap for the logo to fit in. The logo area is separate from the nav menu in the markup but flexbox layout puts them all in line with each other (at lower breakpoints the nav menu moves down).

Now this all works fine and good until you decide to make the logo a clickable link. When you do that, the margin from that third link obscures the hover state of the logo.

Here's a visual example:
[image: margin obscures hover state]

So if you tried hovering over the logo where the margin area intersects it, you would not be able to click the logo, nor get a pointer cursor or any hover states (like a background change). Outside of the margin while over the logo, it works fine, but to a user, they're going to think something strange is going on. This happens if the logo is an img (as it is in the original example) or an SVG (as I'm trying to use).

Trying to see if there's a way around this without having to completely nuke my Flexbox layout. My markup is very similar to what is being used in that example. I've tried toying with a higher z-index for the logo compared to the nav, which didn't work. Giving the nav a negative z-index lets you click the logo but then you can't click the nav items.

Comment: It is worth noting that it happens in Chrome, but NOT in FireFox. I've not tested any other browser. Seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a relative position to the logo and then play around with the z-index to make the logo the first element.

```
.logo {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: You know, I thought I tried that, but I may have been either missing a) the relative positioning and/or b) bringing in the logo div to smaller size (when the z-index of that is brought up I couldn't select the items below) and I wonder if that's why I couldn't select the nav when I set that to a negative index. I feel like this is front-end 101 and I failed, lol.

Also, it is in fact not the margin that was giving me problems, but the entire space the nav was taking up (removing margins totally had confirmed this).

Anyway, thanks! Good to go.